# MaxMinD GeoIP2: IPv4, IPv6 or both?

Tags: mysql, geoip, maxmind

Do I need to import both the IPv4 blocks and IPv6 blocks from the MaxMinD GeoIP2 lite database tables? Or can I choose?

I've found some guides for importing the CSVs to MySQL, but they don't specify which to use, and now I'm confused. :)

Comment: That depends on you and your server. Do you allow people to access it via IPv6?

Comment: @ceejayoz Good question! The server in question is still in a virtual environment, and I haven't thought much about that yet. But I suppose I'll just stick to IPv4 to keep it simple. So IPv4 it is?

Comment: Sure. Your code's going to say "user came with this IP, what location does it correspond to?" If no one's coming in with IPv6 addresses, there's no need for that data in the database.

Comment: @ceejayoz In the end I realized it was much easier to just download the whole database files instead of importing the tables into my primary database. The Reader class needs to be fed a database file anyway, after all. So now I guess it supports both regardless.
Thanks for your help though! :)

Answer (score -1):

Only IPv6 blocks are sufficient. MaxMind already maps [IPv4 in IPv6](https://maxmind.github.io/MaxMind-DB/).
You can also read and try [here](https://medium.com/by-devops-for-devops/how-to-identify-country-by-ip-address-1e9dbcb53584) with the source code.